# How to override the response in Jasmine Spyon

Tags: karma-jasmine, angular4-httpclient, jasmine2.0, angular-test

I have an mockservice and i need to override the mock service response in particular test cases, but it is taking an value from the mock service instead of new response in spyon.

here i have a mock service and return some value.

```
export class MockService {


    getProducts() {
        const data = [{ 'productI': 1, 'productName': 'Phone', 'price': 19.96 },
        { 'productID': 3, 'productName': 'Phones', 'price': 19.96 },
        {
            'productID': 2, 'productName': 'Laptop', 'price': 2000.96
        }];


        return Observable.of(data);
    }

}
```

In spec one of the test case i have getting the above response and test case success.

```
  it('call subscribe get Products and get into success', () => {
         spyOn(mockService, 'getProduct').and.returnValue(
          observable.of();
```

)

```
     });

        component.ngOnInit();
```

In another test cases i need to test fail scenario.

```
it("Test 409 failure in service call',()=>{


  spyOn(mockService, 'getProduct').and.returnValue(
            throwError({status:409})
             });

component.ngOnInit();
});
```

In this case , getting a value from predefined mock respone.Why it is not get into error after provide throwError in spyOn

Comment: Please give a coherent [mcve].